# How to call a function using the character string of the function name in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to call a function with a given string of the function name.

E.g.

```
print(funcList)
[[1]]
`*`

[[2]]
sin
```

works:

```
mult <- `*`
mult(5,6)
[1] 30
```

doesn't work:

```
func1 <- funcList[[1]]
func1(5,6)

func2 <- funcList[[2]]
func2(1.2)
```

So is it possible to call all of the functions in the functionList?

Comment: Your example works for me and the elements of your list aren't characters, they're functions.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Those don't look like strings; that looks like a list of functions. To answer the question posed in your title, see `get()`. For example, using your list but stored as character strings:

```
funcList <- list("*", "sin")
```

we can use `get()` to return the function with name given by the selected element of the list:

```
> f <- get(funcList[[1]])
> f
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("*")
> f(3,4)
[1] 12
```

An alternative is the `match.fun()` function, which given a string will find a function with name matching that string:

```
> f2 <- match.fun(funcList[[1]])
> f2(3,4)
[1] 12
```

but as `?match.fun` tells us, we probably shouldn't be doing that at the prompt, but from within a function.

If you do have a list of functions, then one can simply index into the list and use it as a function:

```
> funcList2 <- list(`*`, sin)
> str(funcList2)
List of 2
 $ :function (e1, e2)  
 $ :function (x)  
> funcList2[[1]](3, 4)
[1] 12
> funcList2[[2]](1.2)
[1] 0.9320391
```

or you can save the functions out as interim objects, but there is little point in doing this:

```
> f3 <- funcList2[[1]]
> f3(3,4)
[1] 12
> f4 <- funcList2[[2]]
> f4(1.2)
[1] 0.9320391
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but you were right.. i dont have a list of strings i have a list of functions. can you tell me how to do that with a list of functions too?

Comment: @tobi as @Joshua mentioned in his comment above, what you did works for me. I have updated my answer to show you what works. If the example in my Answer doesn't work for you, edit your question to show us the exact output R gives when you try this.

Answer (score 35):

See documentation for `do.call`.

A quick demonstration:

```
do.call("rnorm", list(100, 0, 1))
```

first parameter can be a string literal, or R object, and the second one is list of arguments that are to be matched with provided function formal arguments.

Answer (score 7):

you could also use `match.fun`

```
> functionlist <- list("*","sin")
> f <- match.fun(functionlist[[1]])
> f(5,6)
[1] 30
```