# R: get the name of a function that is stored in a variable

Tags: r

In my R program, I have a function that gets a function as an argument and inside this function I would like to get its name as a string (i.e. the function name of this argument that is supposed to be a function).

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403852/how-to-call-a-function-using-the-character-string-of-the-function-name-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for `substitute`:

```
f <- function(x) { substitute(x) }

f(mean)
```

Yields:

> ```
> mean
> ```

which is a symbol. To get it as a string instead, add `deparse`:

```
f <- function(x) { deparse(substitute(x)) }

f(mean)
```

Yields:

> ```
> [1] "mean"
> ```

Comment: I need the name of the function as a string. I will edit my question accordingly. So I just have to wrap an as.character() around the substitute, right?

Comment: That works, yes. But `?substitute` suggests `deparse(substitute(x))`.

Comment: If you add that to your answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.