# Avoiding eval-parse or do.call

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to select a theme from `ggplot2` based on some string given. For demo purposes, consider the following code:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, wt))+
  geom_point() -> p
all_ggplot2_funs <- getNamespaceExports("ggplot2")
p +
eval(parse(text=paste0(all_ggplot2_funs[grep("theme_", all_ggplot2_funs)][15],
                       "()")))
```

This works fine and would allow me to use `theme_minimal`. However, from a security point of view as highlighted in past threads on the `eval-parse` scenario in different languages, I would like to avoid this.

I could probably use `do.call` but was looking at something akin to `python`'s `()` where I can just call a function based on a string e.g.

```
methods = {pi: math.pi, sum: math.sum}
methods["pi"]()
```

What could be an R `base` way to achieve this?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403852/how-to-call-a-function-using-the-character-string-of-the-function-name-in-r

Comment: instead of creating the character vector with exported functions, you could apply akruns solution directly to the namespace with getFunction("theme_minimal", where = "package:ggplot2")

Comment: Thanks @tjebo, it was slightly more complicated than selecting `theme_minimal`. I wanted to get all these themes, store them somewhere (shiny stuff), and then I can later grep based on a provided string but the solution was indeed very [useful](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/shinymde/commit/810cf8f36c5760b59549842870ee754c6d353fcb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `getFunction`

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <- p + 
   getFunction(all_ggplot2_funs[grep("theme_", all_ggplot2_funs)][15])()
```

-checking

```
> p2 <- p + theme_minimal()
> all.equal(p1, p2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Just curious and for learning effect. In which scenario could this be useful.?

Comment: @TarJae. you can use `get` as well, but `getFunction` I guess is more specific to function

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to have a separately extracted list of functions since it's already accessible in the function list. And It would seem to be more stable against future additions of features to the `ggplot2`-universe to call the function by name rather than by position in a list so I would argue for:

```
choice <- "minimal"
p+ match.fun( paste0("theme_", choice) )()
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry this was just an example. I did use a name based `grep` for the real situation. This is an elegant solution too.